# Class Instance creation between 3 classes in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, class, oop, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes, lets call them A,B and C. Now consider the following code :

```
public class A{
  A(){}
  methodOfA(){}
}

public class B{
  A a = new A();
}

public class C{
  //Here i want to access a.methodOfA() without creating a new instance of the class A.
  //I want to achieve this only using the instance 'a' created in class B
}
```

Is this thing possible? If not, please let me know the solution. My application restricts me from creating a new instance of A in class C. This is because i am building a music player application in C# using WPF.

Class B is my mainwindow.cs which keeps on running until the app exits. Class A contains all the methods like play(),pause(),etc. Class B calls a method in Class C (on button click event), which in turn has to call a method like play() in class A using the same instance created in B because that instance is already running and the function has to performed based on that instance.

I have already inherited external library in class C. And C# does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Is `methodOFA` public?

Comment: Provide a property that encapsulates the instance of class A in B.  `public class B {  A a = new A();  public A GetA { get  { return a }; }`

Comment: I see no way multiple inheritance would have helped - if you have an example - please post it, otherwise it feels like empty rant...

Comment: It would also help to know the return type of the method in `C` because if its changeable then you may never need to call A in C..

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I cannot post the exact code as my employer does not permit me to. Sorry for that. This is the best example that i can give.

Comment: @Sayse Yes methodofA is public. Return type of method in class C is void

Comment: Can you change the return type of method in C (or its parameters)?

Comment: @Sayse No. because it returns nothing. It just makes a call to a method in A using the instance of class B.

Comment: Thats my point, if it returns a boolean then you can use that return value *after* your method returns to B and then have B just call the method in A it needs

Answer (score 2):

If you have three separate classes, presumably it is so that each fulfills a distinct responsibility in your object model.

If you need to access A directly from C, given the current design, there may be a flaw in your object model.

You can fix the immediate issue by giving B the responsibility to invoke that functionality in A on behalf of a consumer of B.  To do that, create a wrapper method in B that calls the appropriate method on A.

You mention that C# does not support multiple inheritance.  That is true, but it does allow you to implement multiple interfaces in a single class.  That may be an appropriate choice depending on the exact details of your real problem.